# Processing Server XML Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

So I'm studying for an exam and I only have a quick question that has been buggin me for a while. I use AJAX to obtain a XML file to parse it and insert its values into a select element. This is the code:

```
<html>  
    <head>  
    </head>
    <body>  
        <button onclick="EnviaPedido()">Submeter</button>       
        <select id="select"></select>   

        <script type="text/javascript">             
                var xmlHttpObj;
                function CreateXmlHttpRequestObject() { 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xmlHttpObj = new XMLHttpRequest() 
                    }
                    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                        xmlHttpObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                    }
                    return xmlHttpObj;          
                }

                function EnviaPedido() {
                    xmlHttpObj = CreateXmlHttpRequestObject();
                    xmlHttpObj.open("POST", "agenda.xml", true);
                    xmlHttpObj.onreadystatechange = ProcessaReposta;
                    xmlHttpObj.send();          
                }

                function ProcessaReposta() {
                    if (xmlHttpObj.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpObj.status == 200) {
                        var response = xmlHttpObj.responseText;

                        var xmlDoc;

                        if (window.DOMParser) {
                            parser = new DOMParser();
                            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
                        } else {
                            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                            xmlDoc.async = false;
                            xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
                        }

                        var select = document.getElementById("select");

                        var centrosInvestigacao = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("centro_de_investigacao");

                        for(i = 0; i < centrosInvestigacao.length; i++) {
                            var option = document.createElement("option");
                            option.innerHTML = centrosInvestigacao[i].childNodes[1].textContent;
                            select.appendChild(option);
                        }
                    }   
                }       
            </script>   
        <body>      
    </html>
```

And this is the XML that is returned:

```
    <FCT>
      <centro_de_investigacao id="1">
        <nome>GECAD</nome>
        <local>ISEP</local>
        <classificao>Muito bom</classificao>
      </centro_de_investigacao>
      <centro_de_investigacao id="2">
        <nome>DEF</nome>
        <local>ISEP</local>
        <classificao>Bom</classificao>
      </centro_de_investigacao>
      <centro_de_investigacao id="3">
        <nome>ABC</nome>
        <local>FEUP</local>
        <classificao>Muito mau</classificao>
      </centro_de_investigacao>
    </FCT>
```

So when I want to obtain the 'nome' field why do I have to use

```
option.innerHTML = centrosInvestigacao[i].childNodes[1].textContent;
```

instead of

```
option.innerHTML = centrosInvestigacao[i].childNodes[0].textContent;
```

I know it's probably a stupid question but it's starting to piss me off not knowing if this is the expected behaviour or if I'm somehow screwing this up.

Thanks.

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer Thanks for editing this, I honestly don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small snipset of the problem that also shows part of the answer. I would think that the encoding of the XML document you are parsing is "off", in that sence that the first element of your childNodes, is actually a textnode between the last quote of centro_de_investigacao> and the start tag of <nome.

If you check the snipset (you can play around with the index parameter for example), you would see that the first button doesn't need the index increase to 1, but can work as expected with the first element, nl the one at index 0.

So remove the whitespaces from your XML document, and you should be fine.

Whitespaces: tab, space, newline

```js
// mocked, no real data
var xmlHttpObj;

function CreateXmlHttpRequestObject() {
  
  function Mock() {
    this.callready = function() {
      this.readyState = 4;
      this.status = 200;
      this.statusMsg = "OK";
      if (this.onreadystatechange && this.onreadystatechange.call) {
        setTimeout(this.onreadystatechange.bind(this), 0);
      }
    };
    
    this.open = function(methodType, url, async) {
      var el = document.getElementById('dataXml-' + url.split('.')[0]),
          content = el ? el.innerHTML : '';
      if (typeof async === 'undefined' || async) {
        // no action till send is executed
        this.responseText = content;
        this.responseXml = content;
        return;
      }
      return content;
    };
      
    this.send = function(data) {
        this.callready();
    };
  }
  return new Mock();
}

function EnviaPedido(index, url) {
  xmlHttpObj = CreateXmlHttpRequestObject();
  xmlHttpObj.open("POST", url, true);
  xmlHttpObj.onreadystatechange = ProcessaReposta.bind(this, index);
  xmlHttpObj.send();
}

function ProcessaReposta(index, url) {
  if (xmlHttpObj.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpObj.status == 200) {
    var response = xmlHttpObj.responseText;

    var xmlDoc;

    if (window.DOMParser) {
      parser = new DOMParser();
      xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
    } else {
      xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async = false;
      xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
    }

    var select = document.getElementById("select");

    var centrosInvestigacao = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("centro_de_investigacao");
    select.options = [];

    for (i = 0; i < centrosInvestigacao.length; i++) {
      var option = new Option();
      var item = centrosInvestigacao[i].childNodes[index];
      option.text = item.textContent;
      select.options[i] = option;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template id="dataXml-agenda"><FCT><centro_de_investigacao id="1"><nome>GECAD</nome><local>ISEP</local><classificao>Muito bom</classificao></centro_de_investigacao><centro_de_investigacao id="2"><nome>DEF</nome><local>ISEP</local><classificao>Bom</classificao></centro_de_investigacao><centro_de_investigacao id="3"><nome>ABC</nome><local>FEUP</local><classificao>Muito mau</classificao></centro_de_investigacao></FCT></template>
<template id="dataXml-original-agenda"><FCT>
<centro_de_investigacao id="1">
  <nome>GECAD</nome>
  <local>ISEP</local>
  <classificao>Muito bom</classificao>
</centro_de_investigacao>
<centro_de_investigacao id="2">
  <nome>DEF</nome>
  <local>ISEP</local>
  <classificao>Bom</classificao>
</centro_de_investigacao>
<centro_de_investigacao id="3">
  <nome>ABC</nome>
  <local>FEUP</local>
  <classificao>Muito mau</classificao>
</centro_de_investigacao>
</FCT></template>
<select id="select"></select>
<button id="btnGenerate" type="button" onclick="EnviaPedido(0, 'agenda.xml');">Get info</button>
<button id="btnGenerate" type="button" onclick="EnviaPedido(1, 'original-agenda.xml');">Get info false contentType</button>
```

Comment: So all this time I thought it was some parser problem and turns out he was considering the spaces between nodes, a node itself. Oh god, how dumb of me. Well, after all this time I finally got it.

Comment: @Isuckatprogramming Ach, before we could walk, we all fell a few times ;)